# Datatables footer with two rows

Tags: datatables

I have datatables like these

```
<table id="tbl-cfrmvsreal" class="dataTable table table-bordered table-hover table-full-width" width="100%" data-table="tablekk" data-detail="dthkksub">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th rowspan="2">FACTORY NAME</th>
                                <th rowspan="2">CURRENCY</th>
                                <th colspan="3">JAN</th>
                                <th colspan="3">FEB</th>
                                <th colspan="3">MAR</th>
                                <th colspan="3">APR</th>
                                <th colspan="3">MAY</th>
                                <th colspan="3">JUN</th>
                                <th colspan="3">JUL</th>
                                <th colspan="3">AUG</th>
                                <th colspan="3">SEP</th>
                                <th colspan="3">OCT</th>
                                <th colspan="3">NOV</th>
                                <th colspan="3">DEC</th>
                                <th colspan="2">TOTAL <label id="tahun"></label></th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>CFMD ORDER/ PROJECTION  AMOUNT</th>
                                <th>AMOUNT REALISASI EXPORT</th>
                                <th>%</th>
                                <th>CFMD ORDER/ PROJECTION  AMOUNT</th>
                                <th>AMOUNT REALISASI EXPORT</th>
                                <th>%</th>
                                <th>CFMD ORDER/ PROJECTION  AMOUNT</th>
                                <th>AMOUNT REALISASI EXPORT</th>
                                <th>%</th>
                                <th>CFMD ORDER/ PROJECTION  AMOUNT</th>
                                <th>AMOUNT REALISASI EXPORT</th>
                                <th>%</th>
                                <th>CFMD ORDER/ PROJECTION  AMOUNT</th>
                                <th>AMOUNT REALISASI EXPORT</th>
                                <th>%</th>
                                <th>CFMD ORDER/ PROJECTION  AMOUNT</th>
                                <th>AMOUNT REALISASI EXPORT</th>
                                <th>%</th>
                                <th>CFMD ORDER/ PROJECTION  AMOUNT</th>
                                <th>AMOUNT REALISASI EXPORT</th>
                                <th>%</th>
                                <th>CFMD ORDER/ PROJECTION  AMOUNT</th>
                                <th>AMOUNT REALISASI EXPORT</th>
                                <th>%</th>
                                <th>CFMD ORDER/ PROJECTION  AMOUNT</th>
                                <th>AMOUNT REALISASI EXPORT</th>
                                <th>%</th>
                                <th>CFMD ORDER/ PROJECTION  AMOUNT</th>
                                <th>AMOUNT REALISASI EXPORT</th>
                                <th>%</th>
                                <th>CFMD ORDER/ PROJECTION  AMOUNT</th>
                                <th>AMOUNT REALISASI EXPORT</th>
                                <th>%</th>
                                <th>CFMD ORDER/ PROJECTION  AMOUNT</th>
                                <th>AMOUNT REALISASI EXPORT</th>
                                <th>%</th>
                                <th>CFMD ORDER/ PROJECTION  AMOUNT</th>
                                <th>AMOUNT REALISASI EXPORT</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                <th>USD</th>
                                <th><span id="janorderusd"></span></th>
                                <th><span id="janactusd"></span></th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                <th><span id="feborderusd"></span></th>
                                <th><span id="febactusd"></span></th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                <th><span id="marorderusd"></span></th>
                                <th><span id="maractusd"></span></th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                <th><span id="aprorderusd"></span></th>
                                <th><span id="apractusd"></span></th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                <th><span id="mayorderusd"></span></th>
                                <th><span id="mayactusd"></span></th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                <th><span id="junorderusd"></span></th>
                                <th><span id="junactusd"></span></th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                <th><span id="julorderusd"></span></th>
                                <th><span id="julactusd"></span></th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                <th><span id="augorderusd"></span></th>
                                <th><span id="augactusd"></span></th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                <th><span id="seporderusd"></span></th>
                                <th><span id="sepactusd"></span></th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                <th><span id="octorderusd"></span></th>
                                <th><span id="octactusd"></span></th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                <th><span id="novorderusd"></span></th>
                                <th><span id="novactusd"></span></th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                <th><span id="decorderusd"></span></th>
                                <th><span id="decvactusd"></span></th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                <th><span id="sumorderusd"></span></th>
                                <th><span id="sumactusd"></span></th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                <th>IDR</th>
                                <th><span id="janorderidr"></span></th>
                                <th><span id="janactidr"></span></th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                <th><span id="feborderidr"></span></th>
                                <th><span id="febactidr"></span></th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                <th><span id="marorderidr"></span></th>
                                <th><span id="maractidr"></span></th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                <th><span id="aprorderidr"></span></th>
                                <th><span id="apractidr"></span></th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                <th><span id="mayorderidr"></span></th>
                                <th><span id="mayactidr"></span></th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                <th><span id="junorderidr"></span></th>
                                <th><span id="junactidr"></span></th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                <th><span id="julorderidr"></span></th>
                                <th><span id="julactidr"></span></th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                <th><span id="augorderidr"></span></th>
                                <th><span id="augactidr"></span></th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                <th><span id="seporderidr"></span></th>
                                <th><span id="sepactidr"></span></th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                <th><span id="octorderidr"></span></th>
                                <th><span id="octactidr"></span></th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                <th><span id="novorderidr"></span></th>
                                <th><span id="novactidr"></span></th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                <th><span id="decorderidr"></span></th>
                                <th><span id="decvactidr"></span></th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                <th><span id="sumorderidr"></span></th>
                                <th><span id="sumactidr"></span></th>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
```

And here my jquery

```
var table = $("#tbl-cfrmvsreal");
        var target = table.attr('data-table');
        //console.logconsole.log(host+'konrtakkerja/'+target);
        var oTable = table.on( 'processing.dt', function ( e, settings, processing ) {
                if (processing) {
                    $(this).find('tbody').addClass('load1 csspinner');
                } else{
                    $(this).find('tbody').removeClass('load1 csspinner');
                };
            } ).DataTable({
                "bServerSide": true,
                "ajax": host+'datatable/'+target,
                "columnDefs": [{
                    "targets": [ -1 ],
                    "className": "dt-body-left",
                },
                {
                    "targets": [ 2 ],
                    "className": "details-control",
                }],
                //add by tiar 5 mei 2017
                "aoColumns": [null,null,null
                                ,null,null,null
                                ,null,{"sClass": "alignRight"},null
                                ,null,{"sClass": "alignRight"}],
                //end
                "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
                 // I don't know how to put these code for footer
                }
            });
```

But my problem is, it show error it `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'nTf' of undefined`, well i know what is mean that error, but i need too make second row. 
I wanna make 2 row on my footer, first row for summary currency USD and second row for summary currency IDR. But i don't know how to do that. Any solution for these?

EDIT : Never mind i found another way solution. Well is not best option for footer. I just separate summary into another datatables. So thank you for helping my question.

Comment: Could you please create a [codepen](https://codepen.io)/[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with some data in your table which replicates this issue.

Comment: well i like too, but i don't know how to do that cause i'm using my company database mysql so i can't build. And i just have found another solution well not real solution but it kinda better away to get these case.